# ¿Como puedo solucionar este inconveniente? error #1235

Tags: mysql, sql

Este error me aparece cuando intento insertar en dos tablas al mismo tiempo mediante el detonador t3.

He aquí el código:

```
 drop trigger if exists Actualizador; 
    delimiter go 
    CREATE TRIGGER Actualizador
    AFTER INSERT ON banca
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
    Insert Into  Test (a1, a2, BANCA_ID) VALUES  (new.Hab_Ban, new.Hab_Ban , new.ID_BANCA); 
    Insert Into  Test2 (a1, a2, BANCA_ID) VALUES  (new.Hab_Ban, new.Hab_Ban , new.ID_BANCA); 
    END; 
    go 
    delimiter ; 

    insert into banca (ID_BANCA, Nom_Banca, Hab_Ban, BANCA_ID) values(1 , 'EL PINAR' , 1 , 1);
```

> Error #1235 Esta versión de MySQL no soporta todavia
>   'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'

La única manera de hacerlo funcionar es quitar una de las instrucciones insert. ¿Cómo podría hacer?

Comment: Puedes agregar las tablas en la que quieres insertar los datos, y explicarte bien de lo quieres hacer, o quieres que al insertar en una tabla actualice la otra? Explíquese bien.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de mysql: `select version() as 'v';`?